# Adding quantity fields and add to cart buton on WooCommerce Shop page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to develop a WordPress theme with WooCommerce integration, however, I'm stumped as to how to do this particular custom function:

1. Click on either grouped product on the shop/archive page, but instead of redirecting to that grouped product's page (this is the default WooCommerce behaviour, I believe), enable the div below with the child single products and quantity field of each. Should be doable via JavaScript or JQuery.
2. Via an AJAX or a JQuery script again, once the maximum quantity of the grouped product is reached, this should "disable" or prevent the user from adding more.
3. Add the selections to the cart with the Add To Cart button on the bottom.

[image]

Now, I am familiar that my problem might be solved using JavaScript with some CSS tricks, but I don't particularly know which WooCommerce functions/hooks I should be using in order for me to achieve this.

I've tried this code, but it's not exactly producing the effect of what I'm trying to do:

```
/**
 * Override loop template and show quantities next to add to cart buttons
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );
function quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $html, $product ) {
    if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
        $html = '<form action="' . esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) . '" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
        $html .= woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false );
        $html .= '<button type="submit" class="button alt">' . esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ) . '</button>';
        $html .= '</form>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: You should include in your question all related code… If you are using StackOverFlow existing answers code, **always*** include the links in your question

Comment: No, I'm not using existing code from SO answers. The snippet on my question is the one I got from the official WooCommerce documentation. https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/override-loop-template-and-show-quantities-next-to-add-to-cart-buttons/

Edit:
If it was referenced on an existing answer, then I'm not aware of it. Since I believe my question is kind of unique.

Comment: So where is your own real code attempt?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution (or rather a hack) after, searching and experimenting for a bit.

Turns out, I can add products to cart just by getting the relevant add to cart URL. With a little bit of JavaScript and CSS trickery, I can theoretically create the custom functionality like the one in the image. I'm not so sure that it's a proper or most effective way to do it, but definitely considered a workaround.

Here's a guide about custom Add to cart URLs:
https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-custom-add-cart-urls-ultimate-guide/

Posting it here just in case someone with a similar problem comes across this question.

Hint: Use JavaScript to construct custom Add To Cart URLs. For example a function that changes the `href` attribute of your custom add to cart button on your shop page. There are many of ways to do it. But that's my idea.

```
function whenProductClicked(){
     let e = document.getElementById("YourAddToCart_Button_ID");
     e.setAttribute("href", "https://yourdomain.com/?add-to-cart=3111");
}
```

The most important part is this bit of the URL: `?add-to-cart=3111`, when you have WooCommerce installed, this URL will trigger the add to cart functionality of WooCommerce. `?add-to-cart` is the function and `3111` is the ID of an existing product in your database. So, you will have to play around and get creative on how you would construct your URLs, should you have the need to deviate from the standard way of how WooCommerce functions. Personally, I wouldn't do this, but hey.

Of course, it could get more complex and will need lots of checking (on my requirements, at least), but that's the most basic form of what I had in mind.